# trigger pure css modal using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I trigger below pure css modal using javascript (jquery) ? I need no the label as I want to trigger upon user visited a page.

http://jsfiddle.net/h84nubzt/

```
<label class="btn" for="modal-one">Example</a>
    <!-- Modal One -->
    <div class="modal">
        <input class="modal-open" id="modal-one" type="checkbox" hidden>
        <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
            <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-one"></label>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>

                    <label class="btn-close" for="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">×</label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="modal-one">Nice!</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `click()` DOM node method:

```
$('label.btn')[0].click();
```

Or:

```
document.querySelector('label.btn').click();
```

Or set checked state of checkbox to true:

```
$('#modal-one').prop('checked', true);

document.getElementById('modal-one').checked = true;
```

This way too on HTML5 compliant browsers:

```
window['modal-one'].checked = true;
```

### -jsFiddle-